# Using GPS and accelerometer to obtain vehicle velocity

Tags: gps, accelerometer, velocity

I am trying to figure out how I can use an accelerometer to improve the accuracy of GPS reading. 
Preferably if someone has already written the kalman filter code for it that would help.

Just to make it clear I am looking for a kalman filter code that takes acceleration and velocity from two system that are not related. That is I will need a kalman filter for both acceleromoter and GPS velocity reading and the a 3rd one to do the sensor fusion. I just don't want to spend the time doing the research and creating the model. I won't be using the system for more than 2 weeks after that it is scrapped I just need a way to get the velocity of a vechile.

Comment: In what way do you expect the accelerometer to improve GPS reading?

Comment: Are you using CLLocationManager?

Comment: speed measured by GPS contains little high frequency information and lags the actual vehicle speed. A method is needed which combines both accuracy and good transient behaviour.
combines GPS and a Reduced Inertial Sensor System (RISS), in this case a single accelerometer, to achieve an accurate estimate of vehicle speed. Using a Kalman filter, the low frequency accuracy of the GPS and high frequency response of the accelerometer are combined. The only part of the system I am unsure about actually is how to tune the co-variance matrix Q and R.